# could I modify the code of the signal handler of SIGKILL

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, signals, sigkill

How could I modify the code of the signal handler  of SIGKILL so that I can redefine the acitin of SIGKILL?

Comment: Just at the begainning! I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: First, search the kernel source for functions related to signal handling and delivery.  Then, read the source code until you understand how it works.  Then, make your modification.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.
The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.
 Read more [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Comment: Could I modify the kernel code related to SIGKILL handler and recompile the kernel to redifine my own ation?

Comment: sure you could but why do you need this? To have a process always running?

Comment: Well, now I'm learnging the kernel, and I received a task : to redifine the action of the SIGKILL for specific process. For example, when I use the command kill -9 PID, the process of PID woudl not be killed. Then what should I do?

Comment: you need to edit your question and add tag [homework]. I'm not a kernel coder but I guess you need to modify the signal deliver code instead of only the signal handling code.

Comment: Well, I'm doing that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a function to handle when exceptions happens:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void ExceptionHandler(int sig)
{
    #define MAXSTACKSIZE (16)
    void *stackTraces[MAXSTACKSIZE];
    size_t size;

    // get void*'s for all entries on the stack
    size = backtrace(stackTraces, MAXSTACKSIZE);

    // do other stuffs of your own

    exit(1);
}
```

Then in your main code register that function (you can register with other type of exceptions as well):

```
signal(SIGSEGV, ExceptionHandler);
signal(SIGTERM, ExceptionHandler);
signal(SIGINT, ExceptionHandler);
signal(SIGILL, ExceptionHandler);
signal(SIGABRT, ExceptionHandler);
signal(SIGFPE, ExceptionHandler);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: In kernel, how to implement it ?